# Finding device resolution

Tags: android

I have tried 2 approaches to find device dimensions (width and height):

1. `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();`
2. `((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();`

But both these approaches are not reliable because at times they give me wrong dimensions.  For HTC desire, which has 480x800 resolution, it would give me dimensions as 320x533, which are incorrect. Can someone please suggest a more reliable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked for me:

```
public void setDeviceDimensions() {
        WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        width = d.getWidth();
        height = d.getHeight();

    }
```

Along with following entry in manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int Height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
public static String getDisplayPixelSize(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics.widthPixels + " x " + metrics.heightPixels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have clear concept on below terms,

**Screen size:**
Actual physical size, measured as the screen's diagonal.
For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen sizes into four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and extra large.

**Screen density:**
The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.
For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen densities into four generalized densities: low, medium, high, and extra high.

**Orientation:**
The orientation of the screen from the user's point of view. This is either landscape or portrait, meaning that the screen's aspect ratio is either wide or tall, respectively. Be aware that not only do different devices operate in different orientations by default, but the orientation can change at runtime when the user rotates the device.

**Resolution:**
The total number of physical pixels on a screen. When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density groups.

**Density-independent pixel (dp):**
A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

Reference: android developers site